# Live audio source frozen in Chromium based browsers

Tags: html, audio

[This is how the audio element is shown.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gVVKH.png)
Interacting with it does nothing.

(I tried it on ungoogled chromium and Edge, friend tried it on android device and supposedly a default chrome based browser)

here is the html for audio element

```
<div>
    <audio controls style="position: absolute; left: 50%; top: 50%; -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%); transform: translate(-50%, -50%);">
        <!-- Ogg Vorbis format -->
        <source src="http://192.168.50.15:36000/radiox.ogg?nocache=<?php echo time(); ?>" type="audio/ogg">
        
        <!-- Fallback MP3 format -->
        <source src="http://192.168.50.15:36001/radiox.mp3?nocache=<?php echo time(); ?>" type="audio/mpeg">

        Your browser does not support the audio element.
    </audio>
</div>
```

the source comes from MPD, webpage works fine on firefox (mobile and windows)

This originally was only mp3 stream, I tried changing default codec to ogg and adding mp3 fallback.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was an issue with non-encryption of the source. I added a php script to handle audio instead of passing the source URL. Now it works great.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).